# How to Loop Through a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used

```
console.log(response);
```

and got the following in console (in Firebug). How do I loop through to check if "LMNOPQ" exists?

```
data        [Object { name="Excel in ABCD", category="Book", id="327361517327399", more...}, Object { name="LMNOPQ", category="Product/service", id="175625882542984", more...}, Object { name="UVWXYZ", category="Book", id="260641707360118", more...}, 7 more...]
            0       Object { name="Excel in ABCD", category="Book", id="327361517327399", more...}
            category        "Book"
            created_time        "2012-04-04T05:31:04+0000"
            id      "327361517327399"
            name        "Excel in ABCD"
            1       Object { name="LMNOPQ", category="Product/service", id="175625882542984", more...}
            2       
Object { name="UVWXYZ", category="Book", id="260641707360118", more...}
```

Then as suggested by Baptiste Pernet, I tried the following:

```
for(var i in response) {
    console.log(response[i].name);//gives me undefined
    console.log(response[i]);//gives me another object (it is nested, check below)
}
```

> [Object { name="Excel in ABCD", category="Book", id="327361517327399",
>   more...},  Object { name="LMNOPQ", category="Product/service",
>   id="175625882542984", more...},  Object { name="UVWXYZ",
>   category="Book", id="260641707360118", more...},

How do I get this name now? I'm stuck at:

```
console.log(response[i]);
```

What should I write in order to get the properties of nested objects? Another loop?

Comment: You may Use `jsonpath` library

Comment: Give us the url of the jsonp please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use `JSON.stringify(response)` and then [this site](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm) to visualize the result. It is far more standard than the format you provide.

From what you gave, it seems that you have a member called `data` that contains an array (again, I am not sure because you didn't provide a good format to describe you javascript object).

So let's try

```
for(var i in response.data) {
  if (response.data[i].name == 'LMOPQ') {
    return true
  }
}

return false;
```

Comment: nice.... but isnt it a strange syntax ? `data [Object { ` what does the Object word doing there ?

Comment: I think this is the FF console log, it says that it is an array of object data[Object{...}, Object{...}, ...]

Comment: yes Baptiste Pernet, its FF console log. I'll try this and get back

Comment: well, I used like, because you wrote 'like' in your question... in console.log(response[like]);

Comment: Apologies, thats my mistake, it was just console.log(response);

Comment: @BaptistePernet for(var i in response) {
 console.log(response[i].name);//gives me undefined
 console.log(response[i]);//gives me another object (it is nested, check below)
}  
[Object { name="Excel in ABCD", category="Book", id="327361517327399", more...}, 
Object { name="LMNOPQ", category="Product/service", id="175625882542984", more...}, 
Object { name="UVWXYZ", category="Book", id="260641707360118", more...},

Comment: I edited my answer with the detail you provide. But please, use standard JSON to describe your object structure.

Comment: @BaptistePernet You fixed the issue, I could access the property with the syntax you wrote. I'll also go through JSON Visualization, I need to understand the fundamentals. Thank you so much for fixing this.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
for (var prop in Object) {
    if(prop == "LMNOPQ") {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

or you can use `if( response[like].hasOwnProperty("LMNOPQ") )` alternatively.

Comment: Well, I'm fetching facebook likes by a user who has authenticated us already and checking if my page exists in it.

Comment: FB.api('/me/likes, function(response) {
 for(var i in response[like]) {
  console.log(response[like][i].name);
 } 
});

Comment: extremely sorry for the confusion, it was just console.log(response); that logged everything I mentioned in my question, originally.